# unknown format text/html in rails

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :fasteners

  get 'fastener/search' => 'fasteners#search', :as => 'search_fastener', :defaults => { :format => 'html' }
end
```

app/controllers/fasteners_controller.rb:

```
class FastenersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_fastener, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def search
    @fastener = Fastener
  end

  def index
    @fasteners = Fastener.all
  end
...
```

it does not find `app/views/fasteners/search.htm.erb`

I thought adding explicit html would fix this.  Does this much look good to everyone?
edit 1:
I built everything with g scaffold, now new routes don't seem to connect with "missing template when the file name should match.

Comment: Should it be `search.html.erb`? (I honestly don't recall.)

Comment: Yes, probably typo in the file name - it should be `html.erb`